# How can i make a "dice" that randomly generates a number 1-6 EACH time it is used?

Tags: java, class, methods, random

Right now i am using

```
 int die = (int)(6.0 * Math.random()) + 1;
```

This does not work for the loop i am trying to create. This is the method i am using.

```
public void computerRoll()
{ 

 do { roll();
      System.out.println("Roll:"+ die);
      computerScore += die;
     } while (computerScore <= 20 && die >=2 && die <=6 );
     if (computerScore >=20)
        computerHold();

     if (die == 1)
        switchTurn();

 }
```

The roll() method just simply has the previous line of code in it, "int die = (int)(6.0 * Math.random()) + 1;" i have tried moving it around or even making a place holder for it but if i execute the method and the number is not a 1, it just prints that number until it reaches twenty. 
I am trying to create a "dice" that will make a NEW number each time it is used.

Comment: The real problem is *likely* that you are shadowing `die` inside `roll()` and are thus only assigning a variable to the *local variable* named "die", not the *member variable* with the same name. See Jaco Van Niekerks (and Jons) answer for a cleaner solution that avoids this issue entirely.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your roll-method is not handled as a function. You need to return the value generated by your roll() function.

Try this:

```
int roll() {
    return (int)(6.0 * Math.random()) + 1;
}
```

and then:

```
public void computerRoll() { 

    do { 
        int die = roll();
        System.out.println("Roll:"+ die);
        computerScore += die;
     } while (computerScore <= 20 && die >=2 && die <=6 );
     if (computerScore >=20)
         computerHold();

     if (die == 1)
         switchTurn();

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it work. So the only problem i had was not returning the value? can you explain that more in depth on why it did work when i put a return statement, but not when i did not.

Comment: That you'll need to google.  A return statements returns a value from a function.  By calling "int die = roll()" you assign the value that function roll() returned to the variable die.