# Trying to create a program that immitates a 6 sided dice using the Math class

Tags: java, import

I understand I have to use the random method but thats where my understanding ends

Comment: a random real number from 0-1?  How do you think that would map to 6 equal possibilities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i make a "dice" that randomly generates a number 1-6 EACH time it is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410455/how-can-i-make-a-dice-that-randomly-generates-a-number-1-6-each-time-it-is-use)

Answer (score 1):

The [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class has a [nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method that makes it easy to select a value:

```
Random random = new Random(); // ... or possibly reuse an existing Random
int side = random.nextInt(6); // resulting side is in 0...5
```

In many other languages, there is only a method to obtain an evenly-distributed number between 0 and 1. In those cases, multiplying this value by the size of the range will give you an evenly distributed number in the desired range, and then you simply add an offset to shift the result into the range in question. This is the same principle by which the internals of `nextInt()` operates.

Comment: I figured out the Math class way:  int dice=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);